# Can google app engine connect to a external oracle database?

Tags: php, database, oracle, google-app-engine, external

I'm trying to make google app engine work with external oracle database hosted on a remote server. I'm usging PHP to deploy the project. Does anyone know how to make it work? I installed google app engine on my Mac OS x 10.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use the native Oracle drivers with App Engine frontends since that requires installing a separate extension.

However it is possible to use URLfetch to make outbound HTTP calls on App Engine (as Romin suggests), or to use the [native sockets interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).

If you have a pure PHP oracle database client then that should work with either sockets or URLfetch.

If you'd like to see native oracle drivers supported in App Engine, you can file an issue on the [App Engine issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely interact with external services with App Engine + PHP. You will need to use the URL Fetch Service for that. Check out the documentation at : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

What this means is that the remote server will need to have some sort of a HTTP Service wrapper that interacts with your Oracle Database.

Answer (score 0):

...and the standard Oracle wrapper is [Native Oracle XML DB Web Services](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/native-oracle-xml-db-web-services-11gr1.php)